# Что это за ошибка?

Tags: python, windows, бот, discord.py

Ошибка:

```
File "bot.py", line 135
   if not member:
   ^
    IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

и код команды:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permission(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, time=None, *, reason=None):
if not member:
    await ctx.send("You must mention a member to mute!")
elif not time:
    await ctx.send("You must mention a time!")
else:
    if not reason:
        reason="No reason given"
    #Now timed mute manipulation
    try:
        seconds = time[:-1] #Gets the numbers from the time argument, start to -1
        duration = time[-1] #Gets the timed maniulation, s, m, h, d
        if duration == "s":
            seconds = seconds * 1
        elif duration == "m":
            seconds = seconds * 60
        elif duration == "h":
            seconds = seconds * 60 * 60
        elif duration == "d":
            seconds = seconds * 86400
        else:
            await ctx.send("Invalid duration input")
            return
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await ctx.send("Invalid time input")
        return
    guild = ctx.guild
    Muted = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if not Muted:
        Muted = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")
        for channel in guild.channels:
        await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True, read_messages=False)
    await member.add_roles(Muted, reason=reason)
    muted_embed = discord.Embed(title="Muted a user", description=f"{member.mention} Was muted by {ctx.author.mention} for {reason} to {time}")
    await ctx.send(embed=muted_embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
    await member.remove_roles(Muted)
    unmute_embed = discord.Embed(title="Mute over!", description=f'{ctx.author.mention} muted to {member.mention} for {reason} is over after {time}")
    await ctx.send(embed=unmute_embed)
```

Comment: Пробелов не хватат.

Comment: а где именно? скажи пожалуйста

Comment: @Gan5terone228 Начиная со строки на которой ошибка и далее до конца кода видимо. Везде надо 4 пробела добавить. Если код скопирован правильно.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Там была ещё одна ошибка конечно, но  всё равно спасибо!